# Assumingly faulty FFT result

Tags: matlab, fft

I have a mixer and I want to extract the frequencies from the output time domain signal. The output time domain signal is:

```
Vd = (Rd/(33e3+Rd))*(Vrf*sin(Wrf*t)+Vlo*sin(Wlo*t));
y_t = 11*Vd;
func_ = y_t;
```

where:

```
Vrf=27e-3;
Vlo=140e-3;
Frf=10e6;
Flo=9.9e6;
Wrf=Frf*2*pi;
Wlo=Flo*2*pi;
Rd = 70;
```

I am trying to calculate the Fourier coefficients from the time domain signal by means of the following loop:

```
order_max=10;
f_ = 0;
for m = -1*order_max:order_max
    for n = -1*order_max:order_max
        if (m*Wrf+n*Wlo <= 0);
        continue;
    end

    k = (m*Frf+n*Flo)*T0;

    f_ = f_ + 1;

    Func(f_) = integral(@(t)subs(func_).*exp(-1i*2*pi*k*t/T0), -T0/2, T0/2)/T0;
    f(f_) = k/T0;

end
```

time domain signal is as follows:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIkR9.png)

and the coefficients are:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwYLe.png)

As can be seen from Fourier coefficients, amplitude of the frequency of 1e5 is very low compared to the time domain signal.

I think that Fourier coefficients and the time domain signal are not matched!

Would you please help me to find out the problem?

Comment: Aside from the fact that this isn't an [FFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform), amplitude of 1e5 is very low because the signal does not contain a frequency component at that frequency. What you may be considering to be a 1e5 component in your time signal is likely to be the beat effect which shows up as a sinusoidal envelope at that frequency, but which is the result of two tones of similar frequencies (10e6 & 9.9e6). Those tones do seem to appear in your Fourier coefficient plot (though overlapped in the log scale you chose).

Answer (score 0):

The amplitude of the 1e5 frequency component is very low because the signal does not contain significant energy at that frequency,
the signal being in fact composed of the two frequency components at the frequencies specified by the parameters `Flo=9.9e6` and `Frf=10e6`.
Note that those two frequencies do indeed appear in your frequency plot, and their magnitude also seem to correspond to the time-signal sinusoidal coefficients given by:

```
> 11*(Rd/(33e3+Rd))*[Vrf Vlo]
ans =

  6.2867e-004  3.2598e-003
```

Correspondingly, the frequency components are:

```
> abs(Func(find(abs(f-10e6)<1)))  % Frf component
ans =   6.2867e-004
> abs(Func(find(abs(f-9.9e6)<1))) % Flo component
ans =   0.0032598
```

What you may be considering to be a 1e5 component in your time signal is likely to be from the envelope at the signal which shows as a beat with a frequency of 1e5.

As an illustration, if we compute the envelope with a very simple [Envelope detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_detector):

```
func y = envelopedetector(x)
  k = 0.999; % decay factor
  y(1) = x(1);
  for i=2:length(x)
    if (x(i) > y(i-1))
      y(i) = x(i);
    else
      y(i) = k*y(i-1);
    end
  end
end
```

we get the curve in red which I overlaid on your time signal plot:

[image: time-signal with envelope overlapped]

If we then compute the Fourier coefficients of the envelope signal, we indeed get the component at 1e5 (note that the plot doesn't show another significant component at 0 which corresponds to the DC bias):

[image: frequency components]

Now since you mentioned FFT, it is possible to obtain an approximation of the Fourier coefficients with the FFT.
Recalling that the Fourier coefficients are given by:

[image: Fourier coefficients]

And dividing the fundamental period T<sub>0</sub> into N samples, the integral can be approximated (with an increasingly accurate approximation as N increases) to be:

[image: Fourier coefficients approximation]

Which is closely related to the Discrete Fourier Transform. So, given `func_` evaluated over the fundamental period, the Fourier coefficients are approximately:

```
T0      = 1e-5;
t       = [0:N-1]*T0/N;
y       = func_(t);
Func    = fft(y)*2/N;
Func(1) = 0.5*Func(1); % scaling factor is 1/N (instead of 2/N) for f=0
```